# Image Cropper in Fragment gives "cannot override onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in Fragment" error

Tags: java, android, image, fragment, cropper

I have to throw in the towel on this. I am trying to use Image Cropper: [Arthur Hub](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) in a Fragment and I keep getting this

> error: onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in ProfileFragment cannot
>   override onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in Fragment attempting to
>   assign weaker access privileges; was public

Here is the imageCropper function in the fragment:

```
   private void ImagePicker() {
    CropImage.activity(mainImageUri)
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .start(startActivityForResult();,this);
}
```

And here is the onActivityResult in the same fragment I am using to obtain the image:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mainImageUri = result.getUri();
            profileImage.setImageURI(mainImageUri);
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}
```

I had this implemented previously in an activity and it worked fine. As soon as I adjusted it to work in a Fragment, I cannot proceed.

Please help! Also I am a relatively new developer so please be a bit more descriptive in your explanation. Thanks!

Comment: The access modifier for `onActivityResult` is `public` in `Fragment` and not `protected`. Change `protected` to `public`. Most probably you have copied it from activity class.

Comment: Thank you. That worked!

Comment: See this link may help you:https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/onactivityresult-in-fragment/

Comment: @Mohammad I cannot see the code on that link. I get it in a really weird HTML format. Would you be able to paste the code here somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In fragment overrides `onActivityResult` like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { //note: public, not protected.
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```

and in fragment call `startActivityForResult` method.

Comment: Could you please explain this "and in fragment call startActivityForResult method." better? While I got solved the error, the image cropper is not being called.